# Rotating a class in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi i am doing some things with a slider.I need to rotate a class through three spaces.

```
<div class="slide slide_1">
   .....
</div>
<div class="slide slide_2 off">
   .....
</div>
<div class="slide slide_3 off">
   .....
</div>
```

Here are three slides.when it starts works i want to add a class `live` on `slide_1` then after 1 sec i want to add `live` to `slide_2` and remove `off` from `slide_2` and also add `off` at `slide_1`.This way rotating `live` class on three slides.And when there is `live` there should be no `off`

Comment: Where's your JavaScript?

Comment: For us to provide you answers that best answer your question, you may indicate which or what JQuery Slider you are using. As much information you can provide, the better (or most fortunately the **best**) answer will be provided.

Answer (score 1):

Check [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Tejeshvi/wx38rz5L/869/) I have created.
`var i = 2;
    window.setInterval(function(){
    $('.slide_'+i).removeClass('off').addClass('live').siblings().removeClass('live').addClass('off');
    i++;
    if(i==4){
    i=1;
    }
    },1000);`

Answer (score 0):

You can write it like this:

`var element = $('#id-of-element');
 element.siblings().addClass('live').removeClass('off').siblings().removeClass('live').addClass('off');`

Answer (score 0):

```
counter=0;   Sliders=document.getElementsByClassName("slide");
window.addInterval(function (){
sliders[counter].classList.remove("live");
sliders[counter].classList.add("off");
counter++;
if(counter==3){
counter=0;
}
sliders[counter].classList.remove("off");
sliders[counter].classList.remove("add");
},3000);
```

Same as Tjeshvis answer ( gave an upvote)